# selenium and multiprocessing, collects duplicate pages and does not collect certain pages

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing, screen-scraping

I have some issues with the below code, it collects duplicate pages and does not collect certain pages
in the url example I have pagination of 19 pages, and for example it collects comments from the page 2 and the same comments when it is in the page 3, and doesnt collect the comments of the page 3

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
import time

def get_comments(url):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver')
    browser.get(url)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source,"html.parser")

    lastPage = soup.findAll('span', class_= 'page')[-1].text

    for page in range(1,int(lastPage)+1):
        print(page)
        wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='" + str(page) + "']"))).click()
        soup = bs(browser.page_source,"html.parser")
        comments = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'commentaire-card-left')
        for comment in comments:
            print(comment.find('p').text)
            print(comment.find('cite').text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.mesopinions.com/petition/politique/stop-massacre-nos-artisans-annulez-redressement/74954/page14?commentaires-list=true"
    ThreadPool(10).map(get_comments, [url])
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your actual/expected output? Can you show concrete examples of what you're describing? Also, your last question would make this too broad. Please ask one question at a time. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen In each page from 1 to 19 (in theurl example) i have 20 comments per page, and i don't know why, but I scrap duplicate comments, so i scrap the same page twice and for other pages I don't scrap this 20 comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> collects duplicate pages and does not collect certain pages

Give an specific example, because I'm looking at the output and don't see the problem.

> how can I open 5 tabs with selenium for 5 urls

It's easier to open 5 windows instead of 5 tabs.

This:

```
ThreadPool(10).map(get_comments, [url])
```

doesn't do what you expect. map does something like this:

```
# executed in parallel
function(args[0]) # possibly in first executor
function(args[1]) # possibly in second executor
...
```

In your case the args list has only 1 element so you're using only 1 out of 10 executors.

To fix this you have to define a function that parses either a specific range of pages or a single page:

```
def print_comments(url, pages):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")
    browser.get(url)
    for page in pages:
        wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='" + str(page) + "']"))).click()
        soup = bs(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
        comments = soup.findAll("div", class_="commentaire-card-left")
        for comment in comments:
            print(comment.find("p").text)
            print(comment.find("cite").text)
    browser.quit()


def print_all_comments(url):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")
    browser.get(url)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    browser.quit()

    lastPage = soup.findAll("span", class_="page")[-1].text
    step = math.ceil(int(lastPage) / 3 )
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for start_page in range(1, int(lastPage) + 1, step):
            page_numbers = list(range(start_page, start_page + step))
            executor.submit(print_comments, url, page_numbers)


url = "https://www.mesopinions.com/petition/politique/stop-massacre-nos-artisans-annulez-redressement/74954/page14?commentaires-list=true"
print_all_comments(url)
```

The implementation is not perfect but you should get the point :)